# adding kickstart to a cd in windows

Tags: installation, fedora, kickstart

I'd like to add a kickstart file to a fedora DVD for an automated install. I don't ahve access to a Linux box though, just windows. How can I remaster the iso to add the kickstart file?

Answer (score 1):

- Use a CD/DVD burner application to creat an iso of your fedora DVD.
- Use an iso mounter/editor to add the file to the iso ([poweriso](http://www.poweriso.com), [daemon tools](http://www.daemon-tools.cc/eng/home))
- burn the iso with a CD/DVD burning application
- [bob's your uncle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob%27s_your_uncle)

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of [IZarc](http://www.izarc.org/) and [mkisofs](http://smithii.com/cdrtools).

Answer (score 0):

In the RHEL 5 Installation Guide (in docs.redhat.com), section 2.4.2, it gives a mkisofs command to use to re-master the install media.  You can obtain mkisofs for Windows, I would install Cygwin so that you get a full Linux-like environment on Windows (bash shell, etc).  This comes with mkisofs also.
So, if you have the entire Fedora installation DVD copied to a directory called **MyFedora** (make sure the ".discinfo" file is copied also otherwise kickstart won't work), copy your kickstart file to that folder then run the following command:

`mkisofs -o MyFedora.iso -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat \
-no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -R -J -v -T MyFedora`